# Как передать сертификат в WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, certificate

У меня есть Android приложение работающее с определённым SDK, из SDK я получаю сертификат типа java.security.cert.Certificate, и мне надо передать его в WebView приложения, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Вы об этом? https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/java/java-improper-webview-certificate-validation/